# What are the business metrics I should track to evaluate a recommender model deployed on an e-commerce website?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, data-science-model, recommender-system, model-evaluations

Can you suggest some google analytics metrics such as (click or impressions etc) to evaluate a recommender model deployed on an e-commerce website.